# problem when running configure for PSPP

Tags: 20.04, configure

I am currently trying to install PSPP-0.4.0.1 on my Ubuntu 20.04.2. When I run the configure-script I get the following message:

```
configure: error: You must install libgslcblas
```

The first time this happened I simply installed the libgslcblas via:

```
sudo apt-get install libgslcblas0
```

It was installed and I ran configure again but the same mistake was produced. I thought something went wrong with the installation and did it again and got:

```
libgslcblas0 ist schon die neueste Version (2.5+dfsg-6build1).
```

What can I do? Configure is still complaining about the missing libgslcblas although it is installed?

Edit: I installed the dev, now it works

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies of PSPP in 20.04 have to be extracted from 20.10. The terminal command to extract the libgslcblas

```
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gsl/libgslcblas0_2.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
```